# How to deal with colspan

Tags: html

How to deal with colspan when in upper row there are 2 td and in lower row 3 td.

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">Bill Gates</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please maintain your code

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use colspan in above html structure you can use it like that

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td colspan="2">55577854</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Bill Gates</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now all  have 3